# Read a text file in node.js and handle line endings

Tags: node.js

I'm reading a text file in node.js, like so:

```js
 var configfile = path.resolve(__dirname, file);
  
  fs.readFile(configfile, function (err, data) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
    var post_options = {
      'host': 'localhost',
      'port':'3001',
      'path': '/thefile',
      'method': 'POST',
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
      }
    };

    // Set up the request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(post_res) {
      post_res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send(chunk);
      });
      post_res.on('end', function(){
        next();
        return;
      })
    });

    post_req.write(data.toString("utf8", 0, data.length));
```

What I want is to deliver a text file that looks like the original. but I see that the line endings get turned into actual text like /n instead of just being read as line endings.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: do you mean to replace \n by <br> ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I fixed the issue by switching the data type to ascii instead of utf-8.